# Async react routes and infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I decided to use async router loading and i created HOC like this:

```js
const asyncComponent = (importComponent) => {
    return class extends React.Component {
        state = {
            component: null
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            importComponent()
                .then(cmp => {
                    this.setState({component: cmp.default});
                });
        }

        render() {
            const C = this.state.component;
            return C ? <C {...this.props}/> : null;
        }
    }
};

export default asyncComponent;
```

I used this HOC in my router for profile:

```js
import asyncComponent from '../../../../hoc/async.routes.hoc.jsx'

export const UserProfileRoute = () => (
    <div>
        <Route path="/" name="applicantProfile" exact component={
            asyncComponent(() => (import('../containers/profile.ctrl.jsx')))
        } />
    </div>
)
```

At the component I call action in the method componentDidMount and after action state updated, method componentDidMount called again and i get infinite loop. Also HOC call all methods and call Router again, Router call component from the scratch - constructor, render, componentDidMount.

My component after update state call all method inside like it is first render of component.

First Main component:

```js
@withRouter
@connect(mapStateToProps)
@i18n
@oauth
export default class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
      <div className="fl fl--dir-col fl--justify-b h-100">
        <Header />
        <CombineRoutes {...this.props} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )

    }

}
```

Main component call this:

```js
export const CombineRoutes = (props) => (
    <Switch>
        <IncludedProfile {...props} />
    </Switch>
)
```

When i change the state in User container . 1 - 'Main component' calls 'render' method, 2 - CombineRoutes return UserProfileRoute, 3 - UserProfileRoute again load component throught async HOC, 4 -  'User container' calls 'constructor()' again. Maybe HOC again load my component? thats why my component call 'constructor()' again?

Does someone have the same problem?

Comment: Can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem? Preferably with a demo. The code is ok. It doesn't explain why you may have this problem. It's likely specific to route component  which you didn't show.

Comment: I have already appended some code)

Comment: What's `<Switch>`? Is it router switch? This looks suspicious. That you have infinite loop suggests that some of inner components trigger location change. Otherwise `asyncComponent` shouldn't cause problems. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r3homq for example.

Comment: I think the problem is described in [this comment](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105#issuecomment-287262726), and [this part of the documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component). Use `render` instead of `component` when you use inline functions.

Comment: I used all your suggestions. But it doesn't worked :-( Vladimir at the answer below describe solution and it is works but i think my router doesn't async anymore! Like before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call asyncComponent inside UserProfileRoute functional component because on every render it will call asyncComponent again and again. And it actually is the cause of your problem. You should extract asyncComponent call outside of the UserProfileRoute and assign it to a constant.

Comment: What do you mean? 
 `
const Profile = asyncComponent(() => (import('../containers/profile.ctrl.jsx')));

export const UserProfileRoute = () => (
    <div>
        <Route path="/" name="applicantProfile" exact component={Profile} />
    </div>
)
`
Like this?